# How to use css classes for text colors in angular material?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, sass, angular-material2

I have some code for create css class.But it is not working correctly. How to fix that?

```css
@for $i from 1 through 100 {
  $hue : $i;
  .mat-blue-#{$i} {
    color : mat-color($mat-blue, $hue);
  }
}
```

Error

> Error:
>     @return rgba($color, $opacity);
>            ^
>         Argument `$color` of `rgba($color, $alpha)` must be a color

Answer (score 1):

i all ready found a solution.

```css
@for $i from 100 through 1000 {
  $hue : $i;
  .mat-blue-#{$i} {
    color : map-get($mat-blue,$hue);
  }
}
```

that code create classes like .mat-blue-100 , .mat-blue-400 , .mat-blue-800 etc...